# illegal_argument_exception: Can only use phrase prefix queries on text fields - not on [_id] which is of type [_id]

Tags: elasticsearch

When I search using the following on ES 6.3.2, no problems:
{"query": {"match_phrase_prefix" : {"_id":"ZX-bLmsBFOiwdS-Iwr24"}}}

But when I do it on ES 7.0.1, it throws exception as follows:
"type": 
"illegal_argument_exception"

"reason": 
"Can only use phrase prefix queries on text fields - not on [_id] which is of type [_id]"

Comment: have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a new feature introduced by ES 7.